# Hartshorne Exercise II 8.5(a): How to prove $Y'$ is a prime divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\def \p{\operatorname {Pic}}\def \s{\operatorname{Spec}}\def \i{\mathscr I}\def \pr{\operatorname{Proj}}$

> Let $X$ be a nonsingular variety, let $Y$ be a nonsingular subvariety of codimension $r\geq 2$ let $\pi \tilde X\to X$ be the blowing up of $X$ along $Y$, and let $Y'=\pi^{-1}Y$.
>
> (a) Show that the maps $\pi^{*}:\p X\to \p \tilde X$, and $\mathbb Z \to \p X$ defined by $n\to$ class of $nY'$, give rise to an isomorphism $\p \tilde X \simeq \p X\oplus \mathbb Z$

By theorem 8.24 we can easily see that $Y'$ is an integral closed subscheme. To see it's a prime divisor, it's enough to see locally the ideal defining $Y'$ is of height $1$. But I can't see how to do this. Here are my steps:

Suppose $Y$ is defined by the ideal sheaf $\i$. $X=\cup_i U_i$, $U_i=\s A_i$ is an affine cover. Suppose $\i|_{U_i}=\tilde{I_i}$. On $U_i$,$\tilde X$ corresponds to $\pr$ of the ring $A_i\oplus I_i\oplus I_i^2\oplus \cdots$, and the ideal sheaf of $Y'$ corresponds to the ideal $I_i\oplus I_i^2\oplus \cdots$. Hence I need to show the height of $\oplus_{d=0}^{\infty}I_i^{d+1}$ is $1$. But how?

Suppose its height is larger than $2$, then it contains a homogeneous ideal of height $1$, and I want to get a contradiction from it, but I don't know why. Could you offer some help? Thanks!

Comment: $Y'$ corresponds to $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\operatorname{Proj}(\bigoplus_{m\ge 0}{I_i^m}$. See (II.7.13) and its proof in Hartshorne. (Note that this is referenced in the proof of (II.8.24))